# To checkout the bitness of WIM file programmatically

Tags: visual-c++, winpe

I want to know how we can check the bitness (32 or 64 bit) of any WIM file programmatically?
I am using VC++ for development, i did enough googling but didn't get anything much about WIM file bitness.

Answer (score 0):

DISM.EXE is your friend. Windows 8 or later...it has all sorts of information. Take a look at this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825042.aspx). One thing you can probably do is enumerate drivers. Look for the existence of x64 (amd64) in the architecture column for a coarse clue.

You could mount the wim (dism does that, too)...and then interrogate the registry. That's going to be definitive, but more of a pita and more time consuming. There's reg.exe...that will let you load a "foreign" registry hive - and you can load a registry hive from a mounted .wim. By all means, don't forget to unload the hive...or you will make the .wim *very* difficult to unmount.

If need be, you can run newer versions of DISM on older boxes (to get all this cool new functionality). There are architecture-specific versions of DSIM in the Windows ADK.

Comment: I am now able to get the bitness of wim by extracting its XML information. XML has the tag called <windows>, under that there is subtag called <ARCH> by extracting arch i am able to get the information. Thanks for yoy answer